# How do you get an entire array from a structure?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a board game and want to store information about each square of a 10x10 grid inside a structure, and I need to get the entire array `rects` from the record structure `squares` and use it in `e.Graphics.FillRectangles()`. Everything apart from the declarations are inside a paint event.

```
Public Structure squares
    Dim rects As Rectangle
End Structure

Dim s(99) As squares

'assigning values to each instance of rects

e.Graphics.FillRectangles(b1, s.rects)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(p1, s.rects)
```

but this gives the error `'rects' is not a member of 'Form1.squares()'`. s().rects does not work either. Note that I am not trying to get a specific index, as `FillRectangles` does not accept it as an argument.

I previously had `rects` on its own and that worked without any issues.

```
Dim rects(99) as Rectangle

'assigning values to each instance of rects

e.Graphics.FillRectangles(b1, rects)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(p1, rects)
```

I could use a loop that draws each rectangle individually, but I found that this method is much slower and not what i'm looking for.

Is there any way to make this work or should I have it as an array on its own and only store other information inside the structure? Should I even use a structure at all or would using parallel arrays be a better idea?

Comment: Regarding your last question, it depends on what sort of game you're making and how critical it is to have high performance at the expense of code clarity.  I'd tend to think that a board game (vs. an FPS or RTS type of game) would favor clarity, so stick with the structure if that gives clearer code.

Comment: Code clarity is more favourable to me (to an extent), so structures it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `s.rects`. There is not an `index` to extract `rects`. That  must be `s(indexHere).rects`.
However the code below return all `rects` from your array:

```
Dim s(99) As squares
'Do not forget to set rects before calling those two
e.Graphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.Red, s.Select(Function(x) x.rects).ToArray)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(Pens.Black, s.Select(Function(x) x.rects).ToArray)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you, marked as answer.